# OpenBugs: invalid or unexpected token scanned

Tags: compiler-errors, unexpected-token, openbugs

I keep getting the "invalid or unexpected token scanned", but I can't find the problem. Can someone help me, please?

```
model {
         for (i in 1: n ) {

            dummy[i] <- 0
            x [ i ] <- y [ i ]
            dummy[ i ] ~ dloglik ( logLike [ i ] )
            z [ i ] <- ( x [ i ] - mu) / sigma
            w [ i ] <- abs( z [ i ] / t [ i ])
            a1 [i] <- ( sin(3.14159 * alpha * y [ i ] + b1 ) ) / cos (3.14159  *  y [ i ])
            a2 [ i ] <- ( cos( 3.14159*  y [ i ] ) ) / cos ( 3.14159 * ( alpha - 1) * y [i ] + b1)
            a3 <- pow (a2 [i], theta2)
            t [ i ] <- a1 [ i ] * a3 [ i ]
            loglLike [ i ] <- log (alpha) - log( abs(alpha -1) ) - log (sigma) -  pow(w [ i ], theta1) + theta1*log ( w[ i ]) - log (abs ( z[ i ] ))
            y[ i ] ~ dunif ( -0.5, 0.5)
            }

theta1 <- alpha / (alpha-1)
theta2 <- (alpha -1)/alpha
b1 <- ( beta* min(alpha, 2-alpha)*3.14159)/2
alpha ~ dunif (1, 2)
beta ~ dunif ( -1, 1)
sigma ~ dunif (0, 2)
mu ~dunif (-2, 2)
}
```